# How to refer to a word inside a running text as a TikZ coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Say you have some running text, and you want to be able to refer to some part of that text (like a single word) as a TikZ coordinate in order to, for example, draw edges to that word. What's the best way of achieving that?

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mkTikzCoord}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node [inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (#1) {#2};}%
}

\begin{document}
  Some text where I want to be able to draw an edge to
  \mkTikzCoord{word1}{\textbf{this}} word, without affecting its appearance.

  The edge shall come from this \mkTikzCoord{word2}{\textbf{other}} word.
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\draw (word1) -- (word2);}

  Without and with mkTikzCoord: \underline{\textbf{\#}
    \mkTikzCoord{nothing}{\textbf{\#}}}
\end{document}
```

which causes the following results:

[image]

We see that sometimes it works perfectly, and sometimes it does not work perfectly. Mainly, the baseline seems to get messed up depending on what's being wrapped using the `\mkTikzCoord` command.

How can I fix my command such that there is no height difference, no matter the content being wrapped?

Comment: I guess that you have to control the baseline of the node.

Comment: why not just using `tikzmark`?

Comment: @percusse: Well, first of all, I didn't know about it. =) But after having a look it seems that there's no way to _wrap_ some text in order to refer to the whole thing. Sometimes I want to be able to add a circle around it without affect it's position in the text. If you know of a way of achieving this with `tikzmark`, please write it as an answer. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you think works doesn't do it. By chance you have selected two words without `depth`, while `#` has it. Try with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mkTikzCoord}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)]{\node [inner sep=0, outer sep=0, text depth=.25ex, text height=1.5ex] (#1) {#2};}%
}

\begin{document}
  Some text where I want to be able to draw an edge to
  \mkTikzCoord{word1}{\textbf{this}} word, without affecting its appearance. \#

  The edge shall come from this \underline{\mkTikzCoord{word2}{\textbf{otherg}}} word.
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\draw (word1) -- (word2);}

Without and with mkTikzCoord: \underline{\textbf{\#}
    \mkTikzCoord{nothing}{\textbf{\#}}}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

In the example I've changed `other` to `otherg` for testing.

You can find more information on page 125 (pgfmanual 3.0)

Comment: Ah, this fixed the problem! Although now I have another problem, but I'll post that as a new question since it's sort of orthogonal to this problem...